# Android layout issue when centering image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm trying to code the layout of an item in a list. The idea is that I want a picture to be shown at the right of the item, centered horizontally and vertically. I'm embedding my image in a container, where I put some padding in order for the image not to touch the boundaries. I'm inflating the image into the ImageView by calling the setImageBitmap() in the Java code. My problem is that images are not always shown as I want, sometimes they are not well centered and some other times they even touch the boundaries of the item (even if I set padding!). Could you tell me if I'm doing something wrong please?
Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thing1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="blablablabla"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thing2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/thing1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="7(2)"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thing3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/thing2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:text="myText"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/photocontainer"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1) Try replacing the root layout with a horizontal LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout. (The triple RelativeLayout seems redundant: you could also get rid of the "content" layout, and set the photocontainer to alignBottom on thing3, or get rid of the photocontainer too and set padding and alignment on the ImageView itself.) 2) Set the gravity and/or layout_gravity of photocontainer and ImageView to "center".

Answer (score 1):

In your `RelativeLayout` `android:id="@+id/photocontainer"` change your height to `android:layout_height="100dp"`. Since it's fill_parent as of now so the area occupied on each row will depend of the height of your image. Also add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your `ImageView`.

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thing1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="blablablabla"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thing2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="7(2)"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thing3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="myText"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```